# Adding content of a text file to middle of other text file before a particular string

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I am trying to add contents of a text file to middle of other text file , that too before a particular string. I used the below command to add text after a particulat string like

`sed '/line3/ r data.txt' file1.txt   (this will add contents of data.txt to file1.txt after "line3" string.`

I am trying to add the contents of the file before a particular string. I cant assure the line number, so I cant use that method.

For example,

```
    <xa-datasource-property
 name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain.com:1521:ora12121</xa-datasource-
property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="User">username</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">password</xa-datasource-property>
    <!-- Uncomment the following if you are using Oracle 9i
    <xa-datasource-property name="oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible">true</xa-
datasource-property>
   -->
    <exception-sorter-class-name>
        org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter
    </exception-sorter-class-name>
  </xa-datasource>
```

I want to add the contents of data.txt before  `</xa-datasource>` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some google search and expiriments, I got a stable command to do this.

```
 sed $'/<\/xa-datasource>/{e cat     inputfile.txt\n}' file1.txt
```

inputfile.txt is the file that we need to insert before the matching string

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using sed insert with bash command substitiution

```
sed "/<\/xa-datasource>/i $(<inputFile.txt)" file1.txt
```

this way text from inside inputFile.txt will be inserted in line preceeding `</xa-datasource>`

If you want it to be inserted before the given string but in the same line, you can use sed substitution instead of insert:

```
sed "s/<\/xa-datasource>/ $(<inputFile.txt)<\/xa-datasource>/" file1.txt
```

with the second way, you are replacing matched string with the new one, so you must include it at the end the replacement string

Some people prefer to use backtics `''` instead of `$()` due to portability reasons, but I prefer second form if it is for bash only as it looks more readable for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. But its not working when trying the same on another string. Can you please brief the syntax ?

root@vagrant:/home/vagrant# sed "/line3/i"" $(<data.txt)" file1.txt
sed: can't find label for jump to `his'

Comment: Since my text content have the letter "t" , its taking it as label.

Comment: This is a fine solution when you don't have GNU `sed` available, _e.g._, on macOS / BSD, because the `e` command in the accepted answer is a GNU-specific extension. Note that you can actually butt different kinds of quotes up against each other, so this would work, too: `sed 's/<\/xa-datasource>/ '$(<inputFile.txt)'<\/xa-datasource>/' file1.txt`—the `$(command)` part acts just like a double-quoted string. That could save you from going nuts trying to backslash-escape a double-quoted `s///` expression, say, if there were characters in there that needed to be protected from the shell, like `$`.